# iptables drop all packets that do not come from two specific subnets

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, iptables

I want to drop all packets that do not come with a source IP in the subnets 11.2.4.0/24 and 11.2.3.0/24

I thought about doing something like so:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT ! -s 11.2.4.0/24,11.2.3.0/24 -j DROP
```

But I got the following error:

```
iptables v1.8.2 (nf_tables): ! not allowed with multiple source or destination IP addresses
Try 'iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
```

Reading the manpage in the `-s` entry I got this:

> Multiple addresses can  be  specified,  but  this will expand to multiple rules (when adding with -A), or will cause multiple rules to be deleted (with -D).

I now understand the problem. Since multiple rules would be created, this wouldn't work as intended:

I would first drop all packets not in the 11.2.4.0/24 subnet, and thus never get to the second rule and never accept the packets from the 11.2.3.0/24

The problem is, I don't want to accept all packets coming from these 2 subnets, I just want to deny every packet that doesn't come from there.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> drop all packets that do not come with a source IP in the subnets 11.2.4.0/24 **and** 11.2.3.0/24

To avoid any misinterpretation: drop all packets that do not come with a source IP in the subnets (11.2.4.0/24 **or** 11.2.3.0/24).

That is (with some kind of pseudo-code):

```
if not (from 11.2.4.0/24 or from 11.2.3.0/24) then drop [else continue]
```

- this can be implemented with an user chain and inverting the test

  The condition above is equivalent to:

  ```
  if (from 11.2.4.0/24 or from 11.2.3.0/24) then continue else drop
  ```

  which can be implemented like this:

  ```
  if from 11.2.4.0/24 then
      continue
  else
      if from 11.2.3.0/24 then
          continue
      else
          drop
  ```

  One can use an user-defined chain to help implement this logic:

  ```
  iptables -N dropifnomatch

  iptables -A dropifnomatch -s 11.2.4.0/24 -j RETURN
  iptables -A dropifnomatch -s 11.2.3.0/24 -j RETURN
  iptables -A dropifnomatch -j DROP
  ```

  This chain can be then called from elsewhere (eg: INPUT) to achieve the goal:

  ```
  iptables -A INPUT -j dropifnomatch
  ```

  Ruleset traversal will continue for packets from 11.2.4.0/24 or from 11.2.3.0/24 (because for either of these, the chain `dropifnomatch`'s traversal is stopped before reaching its final drop rule), possibly to reach later rules further restricting traffic, but anything not from these addresses will be dropped immediately.
- or can be implemented using the companion tool [*ipset*](https://ipset.netfilter.org/) along *iptables*

  For efficient handling of bigger network lists and to sort-of separate data from code, one can use the *ipset* companion tool to define a list of networks to whitelist (so its name will be chosen as `whitelist`).

  ```
  ipset create whitelist hash:net
  ipset add whitelist 11.2.4.0/24
  ipset add whitelist 11.2.3.0/24
  ```

  And if the packet's source address is not in the whitelist then drop it:

  ```
  iptables -A INPUT -m set ! --match-set whitelist src -j DROP
  ```

  So like before it will continue only for 11.2.4.0/24 or 11.2.3.0/24 and drop anything else.

Comment: Thank you. This is my first time using iptables and this answer is extremely comprehensive. This is more involved than I thought :)

Comment: nftables might require more initial investment but allows easier handling of such things. Sets are native to it so it doesn't depend on ipset, and can easily be used (as anonymous sets) whenever "or" is needed, just as you'd wanted your initial iptables example to work. So you should ponder moving directly to nftables. Eg: https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Sets#Anonymous_sets

Comment: (Without the boiler plate) with nftables: `ip saddr != { 11.2.4.0/24, 11.2.3.0/24 } drop` does it.